# Jmeter simulating traffic and avoiding 429

Tags: testing, resilience-testing, http

I am using Jmeter to investigate the performance and capacity needs of a few web services. Jmeter sends traffic to the web-facing url (served by Nginx), with a rising rate, to see where the service fails. At the moment, this traffic is generated using a single machine, in the CI/CD pipeline.

Before I can really stress the resources, the web server is responding with [HTTP 429](https://http.cat/429)

Is there a way to set data in the header or something to force each connection to be seen as new, instead of being banned by the server?

Edit : specified that the http server is nginx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that this is symptomatic of rate limiting in Nginx in this case, the solution is to configure the [rate limiting feature of Nginx to allow this](https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/)

A whitelist could  be created in the configuration to remove ratelimiting from the url generating the traffic.

To follow the [Nginx documentation](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/controlling-access-proxied-http/#limiting-the-request-rate), this could be specified as whitelisting an IP.

The current server setup is :

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=flood:10m rate=12r/s;
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=bot:10m rate=200r/m;
limit_req_status 429;
limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=connperip:10m;
limit_conn_status 429;
```

This sets up the rate limit on connections. A whitelist can be created as suggested above, by simulating a boolean condition with a key value map:

```
geo $limit {
    default 1;
    10.0.0.0/8 0;
    192.168.0.0/24 0;
}

map $limit $limit_key {
    0 "";
    1 $binary_remote_addr;
}
```

This removes the rate limit (sets it to 0) if the remote address falls into the whitelist:

```
limit_req_zone $limit_key zone=req_zone:10m rate=5r/s;

server {
    location / {
        limit_req zone=req_zone burst=10 nodelay;
```